# How to access symbols in __init__.py from __main__.py?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a module - let's call it `foo` - and I want to make it usable via a `python -m foo` call. My program look like this:

```
my_project
├──  foo
│   └── __init__.py
└── my_program.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have some code which I run when calling `python -m foo`:

```
def bar(name):
    print(name)

# -- code used to 'run' the module
def main(name):
    bar("fritz")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since I have a fair amount of execution code in `__init__.py` now (`argparse` stuff and some logic) I want to separate it into a `__main__.py`:

```
my_project
├──  foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __main__.py
└── my_program.py
```

Despite that looks very simple to me I didn't manage to import stuff located in `__init__.py` from `__main__.py` yet.

I know - if `foo` is located in `site-packages` or accessible via `PYTHONPATH` I can just `import foo`..

But in case I want to **execute** `__main__.py` **directly** (e.g. from some IDE) with `foo` located *anywhere* (i.e. not a folder where Python looks for packages) - is there a way to import `foo` (`__init__.py` from the same directory)?

I tried `import .` and `import foo` - but both approaches fail (because they just mean something else of course)

What I *can* do - at least to explain my goal - is something like this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
import foo
```

Works, but is ugly and a bit dangerous since I don't even know if I really import `foo` from the same directory..

Comment: `from foo import bar` for example. And BTW you should put only stuff related to the initialization if the package into `__init__.py`.

Comment: This is exactly what *doesn't* work if you're running `__main__.py` directly - you'll get "builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'". It works if you run `python -m foo` (and `foo` is located in a package folder) but not as described in my question.

Comment: You should not run files from a package with the packages folder as PYTHONPATH. The current working directory is the default PYTHONPATH and should be the project folder.

Comment: ``__main__.py`` is mean to be run with the ``-m`` switch. That is its entire purpose.

Comment: You write "with ``foo`` located anywhere" and "I don't even know if I really import foo from the same directory.." - how do you expect to find a module at an arbitrary location? Do you have *some* constraint on where ``foo`` is in relation to ``__main__.py``?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the [module import state](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes) as if `__main__.py` were executed with `-m`:

```
# foo/__main__.py
import os
import sys
if __package__ is None and __name__ == "__main__":  # executed without -m
   # set special attributes as if part of the package
   __file__ = os.path.abspath(__file__)
   __package__ = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
   # replace import path for __main__ with path for package
   main_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
   try:
       index = sys.path.index(dir_path)
       if index != 0 or index != 1:
           raise ValueError('expected script directory after current directory or matching it')
   except ValueError:
       raise RuntimeError('sys.path does not include script directory as expected')
   else:
       sys.path[index] = main_path
# import regularly
from . import bar
```

This exploits that `python3 path/to/foo/__main__.py` executes `__main__` as a standalone script: `__package__` is `None` and the `__name__` does not include the package either. The search path in this case is `<current directory>, <__main__ directory>, ...`, though it gets collapsed if the two are the same: the `index` is either 0 or 1.

As with all trickery on internals, there is some transient state where invariants are violated. Do not perform any imports before the module is patched!